# How to switch criss-cross between windows in vim?

Tags: vim

I have the following situation:

[image]

I'm on top-right window and want to focus on bottom-left, then switch between them like `^WW` easily. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular situation you could use `^Wb` to go to the bottom-right window (there's also `^Wt` to go to the top-left one). You could then use `^Wp` (not `^Ww`) to cycle between them.

`^Ww` moves to the window below the current one, or to the right if you're already at the bottom (and to the top-left one if you're at the bottom-right one). `^WW` does the same but in reverse.

---

However, in case you want to cycle between two windows, neither of which is in the top-left or bottom-right corner, then you can use preceed `^Ww` by a `count` to go to the intended window in one go, and then use `^Wp` to cycle between them.

**EDIT**:
Just realized you want right-top to left-bottom, not left-top to right-bottom… oh well

Comment: What does it mean `count ^WW`? count is a number preceding a keystroke?

Comment: @TimurFayzrakhmanov: `count` is the number of the window you want to go to (following the top-to-bottom/left-to-right ordering). In your example the top-right window is number 3, the bottom left number 2, so `2^Ww` would take you to the bottom-left window.

Answer (score 1):

That can be done. [Check the documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#window-move-cursor) for additional controls if you feel like it.

To select the bottom left window, from the top right window, you can do: `2 CTRL-W W`. This will select the 2nd window, starting from 0 from top-left, to bottom-right, which is the bottom left window.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is an acceptable solution for you.

In my vimrc, I have

```
" Easy window navigation
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

So that I can move focus among window splits by holding `Ctrl` then `h j k l`,  it is straightforward, since in vim we move cursor by `h j k l` as well.

For your example, you can hold `Ctrl` then press `hj` or `jh` to focus the expected window.

Comment: Yep, full use them. I map `<c-h>` and `<c-l>` to move between tabs instead windows.